# how do you make borders collapse on a span?

Tags: css

If you do the tryit editor on this html and make the result window narrow (like 200px), the border is inside the span as it occupies multiple lines. How can I "collapse" the border so it just makes a single (irregular) border around the span?
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap

I'm not trying to alter the flow. I'm trying to "highlight a sentence" like you would with a highlighter. But I want a border too. But I want a single irregularly shaped border, not the default border.

Current problem:
[image]

**[Don't forget to replace the editor html with this html]**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.test {
    width: 11em;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    word-wrap: break-word;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p> <span class="test"> This paragraph contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword.</span> The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT** The fixed span:

[image]

Comment: just add display:block; in you css and it works

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yr6opzev/

Comment: @Monica, thanks but I'm not trying to alter the flow. I'm trying to "highlight a sentence" like you would with a highlighter. But I want a border too. But I want a single irregularly shaped border, not the default border.

Comment: The border-collapse: collapse; is only used for table elements, I haven't seen anywhere, where it can be used for span. Why you would want to put a border around span is beyond me anyway, it is primarily for highlighting/Changing color of the text it is wrapped around.

Comment: Is this appearance you'd like to achieve: http://imgur.com/a/tQNAZ ?

Comment: @myf, yessss :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `outline` instead of `border`

```css
.test {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
p {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<p> You should know that <span class="test">this paragraph contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword.</span> The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</p>
```

Comment: Perhaps good to know that this works well in Chrome, Safari and IE11+ but not so good in Firefox.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be a long-standing bug in FF...going back many years. The spec clearly says that outlines can be non-rectangular.

Comment: Yup; bug goes back to 2004: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=266122 , current spec is https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/ui.html#dynamic-outlines .